# issue regarding multi lingual site php, jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, multilingual

I'M developing a site in `php`. I have set the language session `$_SESSION['language'] = 'english'` and I have included the language file according to the setted session. In php everything is fine and no issue.

The issue is I am using jquery validator plugin. And I want to return the validation errors according to the current language session.
blow is a little code snidest.

code of english lang file.

```
` $lang = array();
$lang['0'] =  "Home";
$lang['1'] =  "Join";
$lang['2'] =  "Sign In";
$lang['3'] =  "close";
$lang['4'] =  "Email";
$lang['5'] =  "Choose Username";
$lang['6'] =  "Choose Password";
$lang['7'] =  "Are You Human?";`
```

for example if I need home somewhere in page I just do

`echo $lang['0'];`

in php its fine. but how can I accomplish this in `.js`

P.S I know the solution like write you javascript code in `.php` file please tell me is there any alternate way to do this or is there any way to import php array into javascript like `jsonencode`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass your php variable in js to use it in front, for example :

```
<script>
var lang0 = <?php echo $lang['0'] ; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: but is it possible to use <?php echo ?> in a `.js` file?

Comment: @SaeedAnsari: If you've configured your webserver to interpret PHP inside `.js` files, yes it is.

Comment: the easiest thing will be to do it in your php file between script tags ( in your view if you are in mvc). You will be able to use these variables in the js file anyway if they are in the same scope.

Comment: lets say I have 10 functions in js file i don't want them all to show in source code on every page where I include the file it will present the code quality as poor. if I include file like this
`<script src="/path/to/my/file.php"></script>`
will it be a solution?

Comment: this isnt a solution at all.  the only good way is to sort well your code first, and to do what i did above.
execute a php code by js require more skills ( ajax), and it seems to be too complicated as I see your answers, try to keep it simple.